# Need Help in Creating History Table in Access

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, i need to create a history table off a select query that is used for reporting?  I don't want an append table as i need the select's data for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that works best is you *do* want to use an append query.

Instead of garbaging up your database with lots of history tables, it's better to have one history table with a unique key to differentiate the multiple history reports.

Usually a "Time Stamp" field is a good primary key.  Where each record in the report gets the same time stamp.

Also, you can have other key fields depending on the type of report it is.  You may want a version field, or a re-try field.  You also may want a final copy field.  Having these fields will allow you to go back and delete garbage reports or updated reports or bad attempt reports.

Also having solid date fields will allow you to discriminate between daily reports, weekly reports, or monthly reports.  (Let alone if you have to worry about Fiscal year, or retail calendars, etc.)

The good thing about having a single table is, you can always go back into your history table and pull out lots of historical data for other types of report comparisons... all in one query instead of trying to tie multiple tables together (mostly with hard to figure out names).

Do yourself and future programmers who will have to deal with your code a favor... and put all the history in one table.  Especially since one of those future programmer may be you.  You'll be thanking yourself.

Oh... and to get the data for the reporting, you use your primary key to pull out that data.   Or... you can have a staging table for your report and then you append the staging table data to the History table (with all the proper key info).